# How Can I Break the Output from same result a PHP While Loop?

Tags: php, mysql

For example in while loop the result will be displayed order by vehicle numbers like this

```
Vehicle num    total_amount
TEST V 1234    500
TEST V 1234    500
TEST V 1234    500
TEST w 785     1000
TEST w 785     1000
TEST Z 589     700
TEST Z 589     700
TEST Z 589     700

But i want to like this.

Vehicle num    total_amount
TEST V 1234    500
TEST V 1234    500
TEST V 1234    500

Vehicle No: TEST V 1234
Total amount: 1500

TEST w 785     1000
TEST w 785     1000

Vehicle No: TEST w 785
Total amount: 2000


TEST Z 589     700
TEST Z 589     700
TEST Z 589     700

Vehicle No: TEST Z 589
Total amount: 2100
```

I want display like dis using php + mysql
how to solve this problem, can anybody tell?

here my code example?

```
<table class="table table-table-striped accord-content even" width="100%" style="clear:both;" id="textttt">
  <thead>
    <tr class="bg-green" style="background:#DBB74E!important; color:#698602 !important" >
      <th>S No</th>
      <th>Owner Name</th>
      <th>Truck Number</th>
      <th>total</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <?php

$query_all = mysql_query("select * from testing where ownername='" . $_POST['ownername'] . "' and dc_date between '".$weekenddate."'   and   '" . $_POST['datewe'] . "' and status='Verified' order by truckk_number ASC");

        while ($fet_all = mysql_fetch_array($query_all)) {  ?>
  <tr class="accord-content even bg-gray" style="color:#698602 !important;">
    <td><?php echo $fet_all['id']; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $fet_all['ownername']; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $fet_all['truckk_number']; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $fet_all['total']; ?></td>
  </tr>
  <?php   } ?>
</table>
```

I want display vehicle wise total and vehicle number.

Comment: Whta you have tried till now?Put your code here?

Comment: in general terms, track the current sum, and the current vehicle number. when the vehicle number changes, spit out the old vehicle number and sum, then reset both

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because there is no code in your question, I use pseudo code here

```
Set track = null, total = 0
Loop through your collection
    If track is not null and current item vehicle_num is different from track
        Print current vehicle_num
        Print total
        Set total = 0
    else
        Update total = total + current total_amount
    endif
    Set track = current item vehicle_num
    Print current item info
endloop
```

For your code, consider replacing this piece:

```
while ($fet_all = mysql_fetch_array($query_all)) {  ?>
  <tr class="accord-content even bg-gray" style="color:#698602 !important;">
    <td><?php echo $fet_all['id']; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $fet_all['ownername']; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $fet_all['truckk_number']; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $fet_all['total']; ?></td>
  </tr>
  <?php   } ?>
```

to this:

```
<?php

#other code

$track = null;
$total = 0;

while ($fet_all = mysql_fetch_array($query_all)) :?>    
  <?php if ($track !== null && $track !== $fet_all['truckk_number']): ?>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="3">Vehicle No:</td>
        <td><?php echo $track; ?></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="3">Total:</td>
        <td><?php echo $total; ?></td>
    </tr>
    <?php $total = $fet_all['total']; ?>
  <?php else: ?>
    <?php $total += $fet_all['total'];  ?>
  <?php endif; ?>
  <tr class="accord-content even bg-gray" style="color:#698602 !important;">
    <td><?php echo $fet_all['id']; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $fet_all['ownername']; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $fet_all['truckk_number']; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $fet_all['total']; ?></td>
  </tr>
  <?php $track = $fet_all['truckk_number']; //add this line ?>
<?php endwhile; ?>
<?php if ($total > 0): ?>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="3">Vehicle No:</td>
        <td><?php echo $track; ?></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="3">Total:</td>
        <td><?php echo $total; ?></td>
    </tr>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: how to get the vehicle count for each vehicle number.?

Comment: TEST V 1234  TEST V 1234  TEST V 1234

Comment: TEST V 1234 : count=3

Comment: TEST w 785 TEST w 785

Comment: how to get the vehicle count for each vehicle number.?

Comment: hii Hieu Le , r  u der?

Comment: how to get the vehicle count for each vehicle number.?

Comment: You can use the same way as I get the total amount number of each vehicle.

Comment: <tr class="bg-green" style="background:#DBB74E!important; color:#698602 !important" >
      <th>S No</th>
      <th>Owner Name</th>
      <th>Truck Number</th>
      <th>total</th>
    </tr>

Comment: How to display Headings for each vehicle using your code?

Comment: hii Hieu Le , r u der?

Comment: How to display Headings for each vehicle using your code?

Answer (score -1):

your query is something like this...

```
SELECT *, SUM(total_amount)  FROM YOUR_TABLENAME  GROUP BY Vehicle_num_COLUMN_NAME
```

use GROUP BY clause.